# Adding product to google shopping. (400) Bad Request

Tags: google-api

I am getting frustrated with this error.
I am using the .NET Client library to connect and to post products to google shopping.

I keep getting this error (I have replaced the correct Id with x's):

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
[GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/xxxxxx/items/products/schema]
   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() +159

In my code I am doing it like this after successfull authentication:

string serviceName = "structuredcontent";
string userAgent = "content-api-example";

GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(serviceName, userAgent, _parameters);
_service = new ContentForShoppingService(userAgent, accountId);
_service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

ProductEntry productEntry = _service.Insert(entry);

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: I've the exact same error, but I'm using java library. So far what I'm guessing is that they changed something in their webservice because their basic example doesn't work either. Maybe the url? But I don't know where to find the correct one.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?
I am still facing the same problem, so I am just about to give up using the .NET Client Library to insert products into Google Shopping.

Comment: I did it in java so I can't quite tell you how to do it in .NET, but if you can get the content of your http request, you can use this tool: https://google-content-api-tools.appspot.com/demo/demo.html to insert the product by selecting raw xml, then in the response you'll find the errors of your product.